# Go compiler doesn't recognize interface implementation by *T (T is generic type parameter)

Tags: go, generics

This is the first time I've had the opportunity to try using Go generics, and what I tried to do doesn't work. I thought the compiler would recognize that `*T` implements a particular interface, where `T` is constrained to be either type `a` or `b` such that both `*a` and `*b` implement the interface, but it doesn't. Here's a piece of code that illustrates the problem:

```
type a struct{}

func (*a) doSomething() {
}

type b struct{}

func (*b) doSomething() {
}

type someInterface interface {
    doSomething()
}

type c[T a | b] struct {
    x T
    y *someInterface
}

func (r *c[T]) someMethod() {
    z := r.x
    *r.y = &z
}
```

That produces the following compile error:

```
cannot use &z (value of type *T) as someInterface value in assignment: *T does not implement someInterface (type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
```

Is there some way to do something like this? Is this something that ideally would work or am I asking too much of generics?